# RadioGroupButton doesn't seem to work with React Starter Kit

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-starter-kit, formsy-material-ui

Here's a gif of it: 
http://www.giphy.com/gifs/3oKIP7arhKhNzNzytq

As you can see, whenever I click on it, it doesn't select.

Here's my exact code which is working in webpack:
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KoaaPYxDno695fiUBMn

But in my starter kit environment, it doesn't seem to work. However, checkboxes seem to work. Any ideas?

```
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-dom": "^15.5.4",
"material-ui": "^0.18.6",
```

EDIT: I also have react-tap-event-plugin and I've called it at the top of my client.js file. Also tried on the top of my Location.js file.

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Here's my full dependency list:

```
dependencies": {
    "apisauce": "^0.14.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.6",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.0",
    "graphql": "^0.10.3",
    "history": "^4.6.3",
    "isomorphic-style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.18.6",
    "node-fetch": "^1.7.1",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "pretty-error": "^2.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "query-string": "^4.3.4",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "sequelize": "^4.2.1",
    "serialize-javascript": "^1.3.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.15",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.8",
    "universal-router": "^3.2.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },
```

Comment: The example at webpackbin works for me so are you sure you didn't add any callbacks or anything to your code?

Comment: Ok, I guess you're missing     `"react-tap-event-plugin": "2.0.1"` in your `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably missing the `react-tap-event-plugin`.
Add it with `npm install -save react-tap-event-plugin`

Comment: I actually already have it in my package JSON as well

    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",

I've tried calling the following code on top of my client.js file and on top of my encapsulating Layout.js file with no success.

     import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
     injectTapEventPlugin();

Answer (score 0):

I strugged with this problem for couple of days and found a solution. See if it works for you

**Why was it not working?**

If you look closely at the backend code of RadioButton you'll realize that it is actually similar to the Checkbox. I realized the problem was not only with RadioButtons but the checkbox was also not working (while the toggles were working fine).

I took my source code and ran it using CRA (Create React App) and it the RadioButtons were working perfectly. For RSK (React Starter Kit) the first suspect which was different was BrowserSync. I dug a little deeper and found that there is a config in BrowserSync for Ghost clicks which was to be turned off. You can read more about it here

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2983

To turn off Ghost mode in your start script, goto ***/tools/start.js*** in your RSK Project folder and change config to

```
browserSync.create().init(
  {
    // https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options
    server: 'src/server.js',
    ghostMode: false,
    middleware: [server],
    open: !process.argv.includes('--silent'),
    ...(isDebug ? {} : { notify: false, ui: false }),
  },
  (error, bs) => (error ? reject(error) : resolve(bs)),
),
```